# Understanding Mental Disorders from a Jewish perspective

Tags: product-recommendation, psychology

Are there any resources (books, online shiurim, etc.) available to help someone navigate the complexities of mental disorders from a Jewish perspective?

My immediate, but not limited, interests are for couples dealing with anxiety and post-trauma. A plus would be resources aiding someone interacting with an anxiety patient (family, friend, co-worker, etc.).

[Yoatzot](http://yoatzot.org/home/) has provided some helpful material.

Answer (score 2):

Rabbi Dr. Abraham Twersky has written about addiction and other topics from a Jewish perspective. [His Web site](http://www.abrahamtwerski.com/) has links to a store where one can buy his books, and has some essays of his entire. I see some titles that appear to be about anxiety, though I haven't noticed anything about post-trauma specifically. While I have not read his works, he has a good reputation, and one religious Jewish psychologist whom I know thinks highly of at least some of his books.

Comment: I knew that name sounded familiar. His Smiling Everyday was a favorite read during Shabbat.

Comment: Who says there is a Jewish perspective? || Significantly, R. Dr. Twerski writes in the introduction to his book that the book ought to be no more necessary than a book for Jews related to any other medical condition. || Note that his name his spelled Twerski.